# How to use a namespace within an MVC view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

This should be simple and I don't know why the compiler is complaining.

I have a view and I want to shorten this call inside it:

```
<div id = "catalog">
        <table id = "catalogContainer">
            <% while ((category = SomeNamespace.Helper.
                                  GetNextCategory(categoryIndex++)) != null)
```

to not qualify every types with the namespace, so I did this:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" 
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

<%@ Import Namespace = "SomeNamespace" >
```

and then down in the mark-up somewhere, I omitted the namespace like so:

```
<div id = "catalog">
        <table id = "catalogContainer">
            <% while ((category = Helper.
                                  GetNextCategory(categoryIndex++)) != null)
```

But the compiler keeps giving me the red squiggly below the type name `Helper` saying it can't find it.

Comment: Does it only show the squiggly or does it not work when you run it? Sometimes the squiggly shows but in actuality it works, all you might need to do is rebuild the project.

Comment: How silly of me. I never tried running it. It does run. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

I just add it to my web.config

```
<system.web>
    <pages>
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="SomeNamespace"/>
        <namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web>
```